# Using framework+mysql in Ubuntu samba webserver

Tags: php, mysql, virtual-machine, samba, ubuntu-server

I am quite a beginner in webservers(and im kind of new to ubuntu) and im wondering how to do something. I have a samba webserver that was installed/running on a ubuntuserver installed on a virtualbox VM.

I installed Mysql and samba and now I can access the basic webpage(Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page) by accessing the IP address of the ubuntuserver on the VM. Now I am wondering how to use a framework and a Mysql database in this. Ive created and filled a database using the mysql command line.

I am now wondering on how to "link" and display elements of that database on the VM webserver website also by using a framework. I've tried to search tutorial online but it is confusing and the few found didnt seem to show how to exactly do what I want to do.

Comment: Why don't you use XAMPP (Windows) for local development?

Comment: I am not using WIndows, im working on 2 linux(ubuntu) machine